# How do i display a form by using a string as the form name

Tags: c#, windows

the user clicks on a row in a grid. The row is a string containing the name of a form. I retrieve the string and want to now display the form. here is my code.

```
    string formToEdit = EditFormsGrid[EditFormsGrid.RowSel, 0].ToString();

        using (var form = ((Form)Activator.CreateInstance()))
        {
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            }
        }
```

How do i get from a string formToEdit to being able to open the form that it refers to

ex. the string = "BatchEditForm"

Also does a default constructor get called such as BatchEditForm()?

Answer (score 0):

Use Type.GetType() to get the Type from the string, than use GetConstructor to get the constructor you want. (You can call a default constructor, or any other constructor)

Comment: I tried this and i get back null           var formType = Type.GetType(formToEdit);

Comment: you should begin the string, before the type itself the namespace it belongs to

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but with no accepted answer, I'll post my own:

This is what you will need;

```
var form_to_open = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("YourNameSpace.YourFormName"));
form_to_open.Show();
```

Don't forget you'll need to replace `YourNameSpace` with the actual namespace of your project and `YourFormName` with the name of the form (in string format).